# Is there any website that generates and hosts board position with PGN as input?

Tags: learning, pgn

Is there any website out there that takes PGN input and generates and hosts board positions (To show as image in the question or answer), till the time we get something like this done on this website itself, we can at least borrow?

Comment: Sounds like a nice small project.

Answer (score 6):

Found one, after *googling* for quite a while!

Here is the diagram I just generated at the URL 
http://www.chessvideos.tv/bimg/3etzqdenimww8.png

### Anand vs Gelfand Game 1 Grunfeld Defence, WCC 2012

[image: Anand vs Gelfand Game 1 Grunfeld Defence, WCC 2012]

The website to generate the diagram is http://www.chessvideos.tv/genboard.php

**[Edit]**
Found another one, this one is far better, it **generates Animated gifs**

### Anand vs Gelfand Game 2 Queen's Gambit Declined Semi-Slav, WCC 2012

[image: Anand vs Gelfand Game 2 Queen's Gambit Declined Semi-Slav, WCC 2012]

This can be done here http://www.caissa.com/chess-tools/pgn-editor.php

Comment: That's pretty slick, however still not ideal for these forums in my opinion--an actual PGN browser would be excellent.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice web service called [Chess Imager](http://www.eddins.net/steve/chess/chessimager) that generates a board diagram from a FEN string included in the URL and you can even [change the color](http://code.google.com/p/chessimager/wiki/SquareColors) of the squares using RGB values that you encode as well. I have used this several times in my posts on this forum.

You just build the URL, which is not difficult, and then bast it in the image (from web) dialog box. The only think I do not like about it is that it does not included a method of identifying the side to move nor does it have an indication of which side is to move. But there may be other options for that that I am unaware of.

It would probably be easier to Google FEN to chess board image rather than PGN.

Answer (score 1):

Something I put together myself: [Diagram maker](http://www.nlightening.com/test/chesseditor.php)
You can have source upon request. It's written in Jquery and php. It supports drag-n-drop and generates png and FEN

Comment: Made source available at: Bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/tnesham/chessdiagrammaker)

Comment: If you need to get in touch, I am EZASPI at Chess.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe [r/chess](http://www.reddit.com/r/chess/) on reddit does something like this.

Comment: I think that's [something you have to download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hplecpnihkigeaiobbmfnfblepiadjdh).

Comment: And that tool seems to be only for displaying PGN at r/chess.